# How can we set spinner items background in android

Tags: android

I have a spinner in my apps.
There are four items:-

item1

item2

item3

item4

I want to change background color of item1 and item4 only.

How can i set the background for these two items only.

Comment: user your own custom xml file for this spinner items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changing the element color**

You will need to write your own custom `Adapter` to do this job. `getView()` will be the method you are most interested in. There are lots of examples of how to write your own custom `Adapter`.

Here is an [example from Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterown) that is really good.

Basically do exactly what he did, change the `getView()` to check what item it currently is and then set the back ground color for that particular element `View`. He checked to see what item it was and then set an image for his `ImageView`. You would do the same, except change the background of your `TextView`.

If you can not figure this out, let me know. I will post a very simple custom `Adapter` example with what you are looking for.

---

**Changing the `Spinner` color**

Use `mySpinner.setBackgroundColor(int color)`.

And do a check to see what value is selected in the spinner and change the color depending on what value is currently there.

*PsuedoCode*

```
if(mySpinner's current value == (item1||item4)) {

    mySpinner.setBackgroundColor(red);

}
```

Comment: True. I thought you meant to just change the `Spinner` box color, not the individual elements once the `Spinner` is openend.

Comment: Yeah, it is only changing the `Spinner` it self. It is not changing the `View` that is in the `List` that comes up.

Comment: Updated my answer. I understand your question better now.

Comment: Keep trying, that example i linked you is very good. I will check back at some point to see if you are still stuck. GL.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below tutorial

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html